# product of sines is less than or equal to sine of arithmetic mean

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

Let $x=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{n}$ and let the angles $x_i\in(0,\pi)$. Then, is the following inequality true?
$$\prod_{i=1}^n\sin(x_i)\le\sin^nx$$

I think yes, by analogy with the AM-GM inequality. But, the application is not direct. Does convexity of the sine function in the interval have a role here? Does Jensen inequality work here? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Hint: apply logarithm on both side. Btw sine is concave on $(0, \pin)$, not convex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sine function is *concave* on $(0, \pi)$, therefore
$$
 \sin x \ge \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n \sin x_i \, .
$$
Using the AM-GM inequality, this expression is 
$$
 \ge \left (\prod_{i=1}^n\sin(x_i)\right) ^{1/n} \, .
$$

You can also apply Jensen's inequality to the (concave) function $\log \circ \sin$ to obtain the same result.

Comment: I actually edited my question. But your answer applies to my previous mistaken question as well!